# Access copied graph in VBA

Tags: vba, graph, copy, copy-paste

I have copy and pasted a graph onto another worksheet:

```
With ActiveChart
        .ChartArea.Copy
End With

Worksheets("Legends").Paste

Dim LegendGraph As Object
LegendGraph = Worksheets("Legends").ChartObjects(Worksheets("Legends").ChartObjects.count)
```

The last line won't work. How do I access the copied graph?

Comment: I was able to acces the graph like this:
Worksheets("Legends").ChartObjects(Worksheets("Legends").ChartObjects.count).Chart

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, then should post this as an answer and then accept your own answer.

Comment: I had to wait 8 hours to do that. And now that I've posted my own answer, I have to wait another day before I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to acces the graph like this:

```
Worksheets("Legends").ChartObjects(Worksheets("Legends").ChartObjects.count).Chart
```